# Передача переменных из класса в класс в "QStackedWidget"

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qstackedwidget

Не так давно я [задавал вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487680/how-to-make-finish-button-in-qstackedwidget) о том, как создать финальную кнопку (`finish-button`) в `QStackedWidget`, используя *PyQt5*.

Но у меня возник вопрос - как передавать и перезаписывать переменную из родительского (`Main`) класса в дочерние (`FirstPage` и `SecondPage`).

Стоит ли мне использовать `@staticmethod`?

```
import sys
 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QComboBox, QStackedWidget, QWidget,
            QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QStyle, QToolBar,
            QAction)
 
 
class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.value = 0
        # Main window setup
        self.setWindowTitle("Stacked widget example")
        self.setWindowIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_FileDialogNewFolder))
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.setMaximumSize(640, 480)
 
        # self.rootBox = QBoxLayout()
        self.rootVBox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.rootHBox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.rootHBox.addStretch()
 
        self.pages = [FirstPage, SecondPage]
        self.stacked = QStackedWidget()
        self.addPages()
 
        self.buttonNext = QPushButton("Next")
        self.buttonNext.clicked.connect(self.buttonNextConnect)
 
        self.buttonBack = QPushButton("Back")
        self.buttonBack.clicked.connect(self.buttonBackConnect)
 
        self.rootHBox.addWidget(self.buttonBack)
        self.rootHBox.addWidget(self.buttonNext)
 
        self.rootVBox.addWidget(self.stacked)
        self.rootVBox.addStretch()
        # left, top, right, bottom
        self.rootVBox.setContentsMargins(5, 0, 5, 10)
        self.rootVBox.addLayout(self.rootHBox)
 
        self.stacked.currentChanged.connect(self.stackedIndexChanged)
        self.setLayout(self.rootVBox)
 
    def addPages(self):
        for i in self.pages: self.stacked.addWidget(i(self, self.value))
 
    def buttonNextConnect(self):
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() == self.stacked.count() - 1:
            self.finish()
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() < self.stacked.count() - 1:
            self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(self.stacked.currentIndex() + 1)
 
    def buttonBackConnect(self):
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() > 0:
            self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(self.stacked.currentIndex() - 1)
 
    def stackedIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.value = self.stacked.currentWidget().value
        self.stacked.currentWidget().value = self.value
        print(self.stacked.currentWidget().__class__.__name__, self.value)
       
        if index == self.stacked.count() - 1:
            self.buttonNext.setText("Finish")
        else:
            self.buttonNext.setText("Next")
 
    def finish(self):
        print(self.value)
        self.close()
 
 
class FirstPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, value):
        super(FirstPage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = value
 
        addAction = QAction(QIcon("Themes/Dark Theme/Icons/add.png"), "Add", self)
        addAction.triggered.connect(self.addValue)
        subAction = QAction(QIcon("Themes/Dark Theme/Icons/cancel.png"), "Sub", self)
        subAction.triggered.connect(self.subValue)
 
        toolbar = QToolBar()
        toolbar.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        toolbar.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon | Qt.AlignLeading)
        toolbar.addAction(addAction)
        toolbar.addAction(subAction)
 
        # Creating buttons
        openFile = QPushButton("Open")
        openSettings = QPushButton("Open")
 
        # First items
        rootGrid = QGridLayout()
        rootGrid.addWidget(toolbar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.addWidget(QLabel("Open file"), 1, 0, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.addWidget(openFile, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.setAlignment(openFile, Qt.AlignRight)
 
        # Second items
        rootGrid.addWidget(QLabel("Open settings"), 2, 0, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.addWidget(openSettings, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.setAlignment(openSettings, Qt.AlignRight)
 
        self.setLayout(rootGrid)
 
    def addValue(self):
        self.value += 1
 
    def subValue(self):
        self.value -= 1
 
    # You can do not use these functions
 
    @property
    def connecter(self):
        print("Value were get: %s" % self.value)
        return self.value
 
    @connecter.setter
    def connecter(self, value):
        print("Value were set: %s" % value)
        self.value = value
 
 
class SecondPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, value):
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = value
 
        super(SecondPage, self).__init__(parent)
        label = QLabel("Second page")
        rootVBox = QVBoxLayout()
        rootHBox = QHBoxLayout()
       
        rootHBox.addWidget(label)
        rootVBox.addLayout(rootHBox)
        self.setLayout(rootVBox)
 
    # You can do not use these functions
 
    @property
    def connecter(self):
        print("Value were get: %s" % self.value)
        return self.value
 
    @connecter.setter
    def connecter(self, value):
        print("Value were set: %s" % value)
        self.value = value
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не совсем понял, что вы хотите передать, поэтому в `Main` добавил `lineEdit`,
значение которого буду передавать и отображать на  `SecondPage`.
Попробуйте.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QComboBox, QStackedWidget, QWidget,
            QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QStyle, QToolBar,
            QAction, QLineEdit)


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.value = 0
        self.mainLabel = QLabel()                                 # +++

        # Main window setup
        self.setWindowTitle("Stacked widget example")
        self.setWindowIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_FileDialogNewFolder))
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.setMaximumSize(640, 480)

        # self.rootBox = QBoxLayout()
        self.rootVBox = QVBoxLayout(self)   
        self.rootHBox = QHBoxLayout()              # - уберите `self`, кот. вызывает ошибку !!!
        self.rootHBox.addStretch()

        self.pages = [FirstPage, SecondPage]
        self.stacked = QStackedWidget()

# +++ значение `lineEdit` будем передавать `SecondPage`   
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Напишите здесь свой текст и посмотрите `SecondPage`")         
        self.lineEdit.textEdited.connect(self.valEdit)

        self.addPages()

        self.buttonNext = QPushButton("Next")
        self.buttonNext.clicked.connect(self.buttonNextConnect)
        self.buttonBack = QPushButton("Back")
        self.buttonBack.clicked.connect(self.buttonBackConnect)
        self.rootHBox.addWidget(self.buttonBack)
        self.rootHBox.addWidget(self.buttonNext)
        self.rootVBox.addWidget(self.stacked)
        self.rootVBox.addStretch()
        # left, top, right, bottom
        self.rootVBox.setContentsMargins(5, 0, 5, 10)
        self.rootVBox.addLayout(self.rootHBox)

        self.stacked.currentChanged.connect(self.stackedIndexChanged)

# ++ добавил в макет пару виджетов для наглядности       
        self.rootVBox.addWidget(self.lineEdit)                 
        self.rootVBox.addWidget(self.mainLabel)   

        self.setLayout(self.rootVBox)

#+++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    def valEdit(self, text):  
        self.mainLabel.setText(text)
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() == 1:          # только для страницы `SecondPage`
            self.stacked.currentWidget().valLabel.setText(text)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   

    def addPages(self):
        for i in self.pages: self.stacked.addWidget(i(self, self.value))

    def buttonNextConnect(self):
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() == self.stacked.count() - 1:
            self.finish()
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() < self.stacked.count() - 1:
            self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(self.stacked.currentIndex() + 1)

    def buttonBackConnect(self):
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() > 0:
            self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(self.stacked.currentIndex() - 1)

    def stackedIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.value = self.stacked.currentWidget().value

        if index == 1:                      # только для страницы `SecondPage`   # +++
            self.stacked.currentWidget().valLabel.setText(self.lineEdit.text())  # +++

        if index == self.stacked.count() - 1:
            self.buttonNext.setText("Finish")
        else:
            self.buttonNext.setText("Next")

    def finish(self):
        print(self.value)
        self.close()


class FirstPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, value):
        super(FirstPage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.value  = value
        addAction = QAction(QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/add.png"), "Add", self)      # мой .png
        addAction.triggered.connect(self.addValue)
        subAction = QAction(QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/close.png"), "Sub", self)    # мой .png
        subAction.triggered.connect(self.subValue)

        toolbar = QToolBar()
        toolbar.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        toolbar.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon | Qt.AlignLeading)
        toolbar.addAction(addAction)
        toolbar.addAction(subAction)

        # Creating buttons
        openFile     = QPushButton("OpenFile")
        openSettings = QPushButton("OpenSettings")

        # First items
        rootGrid = QGridLayout()
        rootGrid.addWidget(toolbar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.addWidget(QLabel("Open file"), 1, 0, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.addWidget(openFile, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.setAlignment(openFile, Qt.AlignRight)

        # Second items
        rootGrid.addWidget(QLabel("Open settings"), 2, 0, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.addWidget(openSettings, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.setAlignment(openSettings, Qt.AlignRight)

        self.setLayout(rootGrid)

    def addValue(self):
        self.value += 1

    def subValue(self):
        self.value -= 1

    # You can do not use these functions

    @property
    def connecter(self):
        print("Value were get: %s" % self.value)
        return self.value

    @connecter.setter
    def connecter(self, value):
        print("Value were set: %s" % value)
        self.value = value


class SecondPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, value):
#        self.parent = parent
#        self.value = value
        super(SecondPage, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent                        # +
        self.value  = value                         # +

        label = QLabel("Second page")

        self.valLabel = QLabel()                   # +++ это будем перезаписывать     

        rootVBox = QVBoxLayout()
        rootHBox = QHBoxLayout()

        rootHBox.addWidget(label)

        rootHBox.addWidget(self.valLabel)          # +++ добавил в макет

        rootVBox.addLayout(rootHBox)
        self.setLayout(rootVBox)

    # You can do not use these functions

    @property
    def connecter(self):
        print("Value were get: %s" % self.value)
        return self.value

    @connecter.setter
    def connecter(self, value):
        print("Value were set: %s" % value)
        self.value = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QComboBox, QStackedWidget, QWidget,
            QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QStyle, QToolBar,
            QAction, QLineEdit)


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.value = 0
        self.mainLabel = QLabel(str(self.value))                            # <<<=====

        # Main window setup
        self.setWindowTitle("Stacked widget example")
        self.setWindowIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_FileDialogNewFolder))
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.setMaximumSize(640, 480)

        # self.rootBox = QBoxLayout()
        self.rootVBox = QVBoxLayout(self)   
        self.rootHBox = QHBoxLayout()        # - уберите `self`, кот. вызывает ошибку !!!
        self.rootHBox.addStretch()

        self.pages = [FirstPage, SecondPage]
        self.stacked = QStackedWidget()

# +++ значение `lineEdit` будем передавать `SecondPage`   
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Напишите здесь свой текст и посмотрите `SecondPage`")         
        self.lineEdit.textEdited.connect(self.valEdit)

        self.addPages()

        self.buttonNext = QPushButton("Next")
        self.buttonNext.clicked.connect(self.buttonNextConnect)
        self.buttonBack = QPushButton("Back")
        self.buttonBack.clicked.connect(self.buttonBackConnect)
        self.rootHBox.addWidget(self.buttonBack)
        self.rootHBox.addWidget(self.buttonNext)
        self.rootVBox.addWidget(self.stacked)
        self.rootVBox.addStretch()
        # left, top, right, bottom
        self.rootVBox.setContentsMargins(5, 0, 5, 10)
        self.rootVBox.addLayout(self.rootHBox)

        self.stacked.currentChanged.connect(self.stackedIndexChanged)

# ++ добавил в макет пару виджетов для наглядности       
        self.rootVBox.addWidget(self.lineEdit)                 
        self.rootVBox.addWidget(self.mainLabel)   

        self.setLayout(self.rootVBox)

#+++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    def valEdit(self, text):  
#        self.mainLabel.setText(text)
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() == 1:          
            self.stacked.currentWidget().valLabel.setText(text)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   

    def addPages(self):
        for i in self.pages: self.stacked.addWidget(i(self, self.value))

    def buttonNextConnect(self):
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() == self.stacked.count() - 1:
            self.finish()
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() < self.stacked.count() - 1:
            self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(self.stacked.currentIndex() + 1)

    def buttonBackConnect(self):
        if self.stacked.currentIndex() > 0:
            self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(self.stacked.currentIndex() - 1)

    def stackedIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.value = self.stacked.currentWidget().value

        if index == 1:                        
            self.stacked.currentWidget().valLabel.setText(self.lineEdit.text())  

        if index == self.stacked.count() - 1:
            self.buttonNext.setText("Finish")
        else:
            self.buttonNext.setText("Next")

    def finish(self):
        print(self.value)
        self.close()


class FirstPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, value):
        super(FirstPage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.value  = value
        print("FirstPage):", value, parent)

        addAction = QAction(QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/add.png"), "Add", self)      
        addAction.triggered.connect(self.addValue)
        subAction = QAction(QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/min.png"), "Sub", self)    
        subAction.triggered.connect(self.subValue)

        toolbar = QToolBar()
        toolbar.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        toolbar.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon | Qt.AlignLeading)
        toolbar.addAction(addAction)
        toolbar.addAction(subAction)

        # Creating buttons
        openFile     = QPushButton("OpenFile")
        openSettings = QPushButton("OpenSettings")

        # First items
        rootGrid = QGridLayout()
        rootGrid.addWidget(toolbar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.addWidget(QLabel("Open file"), 1, 0, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.addWidget(openFile, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.setAlignment(openFile, Qt.AlignRight)

        # Second items
        rootGrid.addWidget(QLabel("Open settings"), 2, 0, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.addWidget(openSettings, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        rootGrid.setAlignment(openSettings, Qt.AlignRight)

        self.setLayout(rootGrid)

    def addValue(self):
#        self.value += 1                                             # ---
        self.parent.value = self.parent.value + 1                    # <<<=====
        self.parent.mainLabel.setText(str(self.parent.value))        # <<<=====

    def subValue(self):
#        self.value -= 1                                             # ---
        self.parent.value = self.parent.value - 1                    # <<<=====
        self.parent.mainLabel.setText(str(self.parent.value))        # <<<===== 

    # You can do not use these functions

    @property
    def connecter(self):
        print("Value were get: %s" % self.value)
        return self.value

    @connecter.setter
    def connecter(self, value):
        print("Value were set: %s" % value)
        self.value = value


class SecondPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, value):
#        self.parent = parent
#        self.value = value
        super(SecondPage, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent                        
        self.value  = value                         

        label = QLabel("Second page")

        self.valLabel = QLabel()                     

        rootVBox = QVBoxLayout()
        rootHBox = QHBoxLayout()

        rootHBox.addWidget(label)

        rootHBox.addWidget(self.valLabel)          

        rootVBox.addLayout(rootHBox)
        self.setLayout(rootVBox)

    # You can do not use these functions

    @property
    def connecter(self):
        print("Value were get: %s" % self.value)
        return self.value

    @connecter.setter
    def connecter(self, value):
        print("Value were set: %s" % value)
        self.value = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хороший пример! Но мне надо передавать переменную `self.value` (та, что в начале тела класса `Main`) в каждый следующий класс (виджет).
После в каждом последующем классе поменять значение переменной (к примеру, в первом есть кнопки сложения и вычитания), а потом передать это в следующий; в конце вернуть в главный класс.

Comment: @jcommander это еще проще, т.к. у вас все написано. Смотрите обновление.